# I want to change the date and time of logs in Java

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I'm using:

```
  logger.info(str);
```

The output is;

```
**Mar 02, 2021 12:01:36 PM** hardwarelog.CustomLogger writeLog
INFO: {"status":true,"message":"success","status_code":200}
```

The date that gets added is system date and time. I want to remove it and add epoch time instead.

How will I do it?

Comment: Depends on the logging framework you're using.

Comment: Could you pls elaborate?

Comment: No, I cannot, because I have no idea which logging framework you're using. Log4J? JUL? Logback? ...?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I'm using Logback.

Comment: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Use AOP to save the log and define a single format for date & time.

Comment: How to do that?